# C++ cin.get(); functioning oddly?

Tags: c++, input, std, cin

I'm new to C++. I was messing around creating a simple program that took the two numbers you inputted and displayed the answer. The only problem was that it closed too fast. I decided to do what I usually do and and a `cin.get();` and it usually solves the problem. The weird thing is, this time it didn't. I had to put two `cin.get();` statements. I'm curious to why it requires me to put two for it to stay open instead of the usual one. Here is my code:

```
int a;
    cin >> a;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << a + b;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the last input (b value) you are also giving a `new line` as input (when you press enter). So the first `cin.get()` is taking that new line as another input. And the last one then keeps your console open.

Adding `cin.ignore();` after `cin>>b;` should solve the problem.

Comment: How would I fix the problem?

Comment: The Rolls-Royce version is `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` which means to discard all of the rest of the input (if any) after the `b` was read.

Comment: won't Just adding `cin.ignore()` after `cin>>b` work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cin.ignore();` instead. That should fix your problem.